# Worklight Update Hangs

Tags: android, updates, ibm-mobilefirst

When updating an application on Worklight server, the application informs my device to update. When the update starts, it completes to 100%, however the dialog never disappears and the application doesn't restart. How do you have the application automatically restart?

I'm using Worklight Server v5.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

The applications is supposed to reload after the download is complete. Something happens that interferes, but you didn't provide any information on:

- the Worklight setup, project and application
- the contents of the update (size)
- the used Android version
- any LogCat logs
- whether this happens on device or emulator

In any case... Check with Worklight 5.0.6.1 (search for "worklight" in the Eclipse Marketplace (available via the Help menu in Eclipse)), where such issues have been resolved.

If the problem persists after upgrading, provide the information mentioned above.